# Core Data - insertNewObjectForEntityForName debug

Tags: core-data

I'm trying to figure out why insertNewObjectForEntityForName is not working. I assume it's something to do with my data model but can't be sure. Xcode does not report any errors nor does it crash. All I get is the first log statement output to the console.

```
NSLog(@"Get here...");
Task *task = (Task *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext:insertionContext];
NSLog(@"but never get here...");
```

Any suggestions as to how I can work out what the problem is?

Comment: Note that your cast to Task* is completely unnecessary. NSEntityDescription returns an id which never needs to be cast.  Just assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume an exception occurs in line 2.
Try the following

```
@try
{
    NSLog(@"Get here...");
    Task *task = (Task *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext:insertionContext];
    NSLog(@"but never get here...");
}
@catch (NSException * e)
{
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
}
```

Comment: That turned up "Exception: +entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name Task".
So, it looks like that hasn't been set up - thanks.